# Finish a proof of existence and uniqueness for a nonlinear pde with initial conditions.

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, banach-fixed-point

Let $Q_T=\mathbb{R}\times (0,T)$ and $X=\{u\in L^{\infty}(Q_T):\,\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(Q_T)}\leq1\}$. For $u\in X$, define $$N(u)(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \int_{x-(t-s)}^{x+(t-s)}(u^2+g)(y,s)\,dy\,ds.$$ Suppose that $T<1$ and $\|g\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)}\leq1$. I proved that $N:X\rightarrow X$ is a contraction, and since $X$ is a complete metric space (because it is closed in $L^\infty(Q_T)$), by Banach fixed point theorem there exists a unique $u\in X$ such that $u=N(u)$.

I read that this implies that the nonlinear problem $$\begin{cases} u_{tt}-u_{xx}=u^2(x,t)+g(x,t),\;(x,t)\in Q_T \\ u(x,0)=0,\;x\in\mathbb{R} \\ u_t(x,0)=0,\; x\in\mathbb{R} \end{cases}$$ has a unique solution in $X$. By d'Alembert's formula I understand that if $u=N(u)$, then $u$ is the unique solution, but I think assuming that $f(x,t)=u^2(x,t)+g(x,t)$ satisfies $f$ and $f_x$ continuous (hypotheses for d'Alembert's formula). Thus, do we have to include some sort of continuity or regularity in the space $X$? Or from $u\in L^\infty(Q_T)$ and $u=N(u)$ we can deduce that $u\in C^2(Q_T)$, and therefore there are no regularity problems?

Comment: I think you are correct that there are some issues with regularity here. It is easy to see that $N(u)$ is always continuous, but if the fixed point $u = N(u)$ is $C^2$, then this automatically implies that $g$ is continuous, which is not in your assumptions. (Do you maybe want to add that assumption? Otherwise the PDE can only be satisfied a.e. or in the weak sense or something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=u^2+g$. By d'Alembert's formula, we need $f$ and $f_x$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$.

Using $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(Q_T)}<\infty$, $u=N(u)$ and dominated convergence, one has $u$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$.

**Assume $g$ and $g_x$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$**. As $f$ is continuous, $$\partial_x \int_{x-(t-s)}^{x+(t-s)}(u^2+g)(y,s)\,dy=(u^2+g)(x+(t-s),s)-(u^2+g)(x-(t-s),s).$$

Use the following result: if $H(x)=\int_a^b h(x,y)\,dy$, $h$ continuous and $h_x$ continuous on $[a,b]$, then there exists $H'(x)=\int_a^b h_x(x,y)\,dy$.

From the result and $u=N(u)$, there exists 
\begin{align*}
u_x(x,t)= {} & \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \left(\partial_x \int_{x-(t-s)}^{x+(t-s)}(u^2+g)(y,s)\,dy\right)\,ds \\= {} & \frac12\int_0^t \left((u^2+g)(x+(t-s),s)-(u^2+g)(x-(t-s),s)\right)\,ds \end{align*} continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$. Then there exists $f_x$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$.